# Indexing a Subquery SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table of dates and a fruit that I ate on that date. A fruit cannot appear with a single date more than once.

```
id | Fruit | Date |
--------------------
 1 | Apple | 5/12 |
 2 | Mango | 5/12 |
 3 | Grape | 5/13 |
 4 | Apple | 5/14 |
 5 | Grape | 5/14 |
 6 | Apple | 5/16 |
 7 | Apple | 5/17 |
```

Given a specific date and a fruit (therefore a specific row) I am trying to find the rows with a date before that given date that also have the same fruit... but a specific index of that subset of rows.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM M1Bars WHERE Date <= 5/16 AND Fruit = 'Apple'
)
WHERE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id DEC)=shift;
```

Assume the given row is 6.

In the inner select, im filtering out all the rows that are after row 6 and dont have Apple, so I should be left with rows [1, 4, 6].

If shift = 1, I want row 4.

if shift = 2, I want row 1.

Thats what Im trying to do with the outer select. How do I do this in sqlite?

EDIT: also assume that the table is sorted by Date!

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't have a DATE datatype, so for this to work, your dates should be in
a numeric or string sortable format, like for example 20220516 (YYYYMMDD).

Then for your query, a left join should do the job

```
select  t1.Fruit, t1.id, t1.Date, t2.id, t2.Date
from M1Bars t1 left join M1bars t2 on t2.Fruit=t1.Fruit and t2.Date < t1.Date
```

This is not the full solution, but following this line you can add row numbers and and an additional join criteria based on shift between row numbers.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must change the format of the dates to the only valid text format for SQLite which is `YYYY-MM-DD`, so that the dates are comparable.

There is no need for a window function, not even a subquery.
You can apply the condition that you want in the `OFFSET` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM M1Bars 
WHERE Date <= '2022-05-16' AND Fruit = 'Apple'
ORDER BY Date DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET <shift>; -- change <shift> with the value that you want
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/zXX--kPb).